# Android Push notification Phonegap HTML5

Tags: android, cordova

I confuse about push notification using PhoneGap, I build android apps without native code (Android Studio) and it work fine but without push notification.

Can I build Android apps with push notification without Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Use pushplugin cordova plugin.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Sample code:

PushCustom.js

```
// JavaScript Document
var pushNotification;

function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {}, false);
        try {
            pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
            if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform ==
                'amazon-fireos') {
                pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {
                    "senderID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "ecb": "onNotification"
                }); // required!
            } else {
                pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
                    "badge": "true",
                    "sound": "true",
                    "alert": "true",
                    "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
                }); // required!
            }
        } catch (err) {
            txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
            txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
            alert(txt);
        }
    }
    // handle APNS notifications for iOS

function onNotificationAPN(e) {
        if (e.alert) {
            // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
            navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
        }
        if (e.sound) {
            // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
            var snd = new Media(e.sound);
            snd.play();
        }
        if (e.badge) {
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
        }
    }
    // handle GCM notifications for Android

function onNotification(e) {
    switch (e.event) {
        case 'registered':
            if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                alert("regID = " + e.regid);
            }
            break;
        case 'message':
            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
            if (e.foreground) {
                // on Android soundname is outside the payload.
                // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + soundfile);
                my_media.play();
            }
            break;
        case 'error':
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function tokenHandler(result) {
    alert('device token = ' + result);
    // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
    // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
}

function successHandler(result) {}

function errorHandler(error) {}
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/08/29/implement-push-notifications-for-android-and-ios-phonegap-part-1/

Comment: i still not understand with you mean, i have create push notif using PHP (post & get API client-server) in iOS apps native language, but im not understand with android if i using phonegap, do you have some example project for this?

Comment: You can check here, http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/08/29/implement-push-notifications-for-android-and-ios-phonegap-part-1/